# define GEOGRAPHY point variable in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried:

```
point GEOGRAPHY 
point := ST_MAKEPOINT(-2.6661587, 53.368992)
```

without success. Is this possible? To be used in SQL further down.

PS:

This:

```
BEGIN
    LET point GEOGRAPHY := ST_MAKEPOINT(-2.6661587, 53);
    RETURN point;
END;

SELECT
    st_distance(:point, POLYGON) AS some_distance
FROM "bla"."di"."bla"
WHERE
    1=1
ORDER BY st_distance(:point, POLYGON) ASC
```

throws:

```
Error: Bind variable :point not set. (line 7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Snowflake Scripting block:

```
BEGIN
   LET point GEOGRAPHY := ST_MAKEPOINT(-2.6661587, 53.368992);
   RETURN point;
END;
```

Output:

```
{"coordinates":[-2.666158700000000e+00,5.336899200000000e+01],"type":"Point"}
```

---

EDIT:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE some_table
AS
SELECT ST_MAKEPOINT(-2.6661587, 54) POLYGON;

DECLARE 
    point GEOGRAPHY;
    rs    RESULTSET;
BEGIN
    point := ST_MAKEPOINT(-2.6661587, 53);

    rs := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  
            $$SELECT st_distance(TO_GEOGRAPHY(?), POLYGON) AS distance
            FROM some_table
            WHERE 1=1
            ORDER BY distance ASC$$ 
       USING (point));

    RETURN TABLE(rs);
END;
```

Output:

```
DISTANCE
111,195.101177485
```

Comment: thanks. can this be used in a sql statement like this: .... st_distance(point, POLYGON) ... where POLYGON is a column of type  GEOGRAPHY in a table?

Comment: @cs0815 You could refer the variable in select using `:point`

Comment: thanks - I get weird SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 62 unexpected '<EOF>'. just with your 4 lines ...

Comment: @cs0815 I suggest to use Snowsight UI - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/running-examples

Comment: Thanks this helped but the sql (see edited PS) throws error ..

Comment: @cs0815 The code you shared in `PS` section is incorrect, because variable is visible only inside BEGIN-END block